# Assertion Failure To Certain Point

Tags: c, malloc, assertion

I keep getting this malloc.c assertion failure. I've looked at other similar questions but can't seem to find a solution. This is my code...I've placed a printf at the spot JUST before it errors out.

```
int ParseCommand(char *cmd_line, struct command_t *cmd, char **paths)
{
    int argc;
    char **line_ptr;
    char *tmp_name = (char *) malloc(sizeof(MAX_PATH_LEN));

    /* Initialization */
    line_ptr = &cmd_line;
    argc = 0;
    cmd->argv[argc] = (char *) malloc(MAX_ARG_LEN);

    /* Fill argv[] Array */
    while((cmd->argv[argc] = strsep(line_ptr, WHITESPACE)) != NULL) {
        cmd->argv[++argc] = (char *) malloc(MAX_ARG_LEN);
    }

    /* Set The Command Name & argc */
    cmd->argc = argc - 1;
    tmp_name = LookupPath(cmd->argv, paths);

    if(tmp_name == NULL) {
        Fatal("Command Not Found!");
    }
    printf("HERE 4\n");
    cmd->name = (char *) malloc(sizeof(tmp_name));
    strncpy(cmd->name, tmp_name, MAX_PATH_LEN);
    free(tmp_name);
}
```

Error is:

```
smallsh: malloc.c:2369: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long)old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You've allocated space for one `char` pointer in this line: `cmd->name = (char *) malloc(sizeof(tmp_name));` but I can't tell if that's what caused it.

Comment: Run it with valgrind to get exact details on the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`malloc(sizeof(tmp_name))` will allocate enough space to store *one pointer*. You then copy up to `MAX_PATH_LEN` bytes into that allocation, which is clearly wrong.

You should replace the `sizeof(...)` with a correct size calculation, probably `1 + strlen(...)`.

Also, `strncpy` will not null terminate the destination buffer if there is no null terminator within the first `MAX_PATH_LEN` bytes of `tmp_name`. This is probably a bug.

Answer (score 0):

This usually means that your heap data is corrupted, i.e. the data structures used by `libc` memory manager are corrupted. It is difficult to see what caused it (especially given only one function of the whole program.) Consider using a tool like [dmalloc](http://dmalloc.com/) or a similar one to find the point at which your program corrupts the heap.